# How to describe a function of two normal distributed random variables

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, lognormal-distribution

I consider the generic problem $W(X,Y)=-2\ln(\frac{(X-Y)^2}{2(X^2+Y^2)})$ where $X$ and $Y$ are normally distributed random variables

Can I make any statements about the distribution of $W$?

Comment: Notice that $(X+Y)^2/(X^2+Y^2)$ will be greater than 1 when $X$ and $Y$ are both of the same sign. Which means that $1-(X+Y)^2/(X^2+Y^2)$ will be negative then, which is going to make it hard to take logs if you want $W$ to be real. Are you sure the function is correct?

Comment: Maybe missing a 2 in the denominator next to $X^2+Y^2$?

Comment: Yes thank you −2ln(1−5(X+Y)^2/2(X^2+Y^2) would be right. Or say at least: How do I treat a generic function of two random variables provided the function is well defined and real :)
Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: Your new function will have an even worse problem than your original. Please edit your question to reflect what it is you want to ask.

Comment: Now it should work better. Sorry for my confusion :)
−2ln((X−Y)^2/2(X^2+Y^2))

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ *independently* distributed normal variables?  Also, can you explain the motivation for this transformation?

Comment: X and Y are normally distributed variables with zero mean and same variance (µ=0,σ^2).
The problem arrises when you consider Wilk's theorem. It states that -2*ln(Λ) approaches a chi-square distribution when the number of samples goes to infinity and where Λ is the likelihood ratio of two hypothesis about nested parametric models. 
The question is now: which distribution do we have instead when the number of samples is only 2 and not infinity. 
H0 is here that we have a normal distribution (µ=0,σ^2) and H(alternative) is that we have any normal distribution with (µ,σ^2).

Answer (score 2):

I will sketch the basic idea on the assumption that  $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

If $X \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ and $Y \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ are independent, then it can be shown that:

$$Z = \frac{(X-Y)^2}{2(X^2+Y^2)} $$

... has an ArcSine(0,1) distribution with pdf say $f(z)$:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/ArcSine01pdf.png))</sub>

We seek the transform $W =-2 \ln(Z)$, which has pdf, say $h(w)$:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/TransformArcSine.png))</sub>

with domain of support on the positive real line (*i.e.* $W>0$). All done.

**Quick check**

The following plot compares the theoretical pdf derived above  $h(w)$ (red dashed) to a Monte Carlo approximation of the pdf of $W$ ( blue squiggly):

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/Checkarcsinetransform.png))</sub>

Looks fine.

**Notes**

1. The `Transform` function used above to help automate is from the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica*.

Comment: Thanks for the comment update that $X \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ and $Y \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$. The answer above has been updated to reflect same ... the solution remains the same for all $\sigma$. :)